# Adding a text in a specified line of rich textbox in c#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

How Can i add a text in a special line of rich text box...
example:
I want to add"This Text" to Line 6

Comment: Are you wanting to do this dynamically.. what are you doing i.e what process are you using to fill the rich text box.. are you familiar with using a List<T> need more information to provide a better suggestion

Comment: Are we talking about a WPF ([`System.Windows.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx)) or WinForms ([`System.Windows.Forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.80).aspx)) `RichTextBox`? Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You can as long as the line number is available

Example :

```
string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
lines[6] = "This Text";
richTextBox1.Lines = lines;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the .Lines property, which is a string[], and is read-writable...but I think you'd have to insert the empty lines in front of line 6 if they weren't there already.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, in Windows Forms you can do that using [`RichTextBox.Lines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property.

In [WPF `RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) this is a bit trickier: you'd need to get a [`TextPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.aspx) for the beginning of the line, move it down 7 lines and then back one position, and then insert the text there.  Something like this (I'm not near a Visual Studio, this may not compile!):

```
public static void InsertText(RichTextBox richText, int line, string text) {
    // Find the position at the end of the specified line.
    var documentStart = richText.Document.ContentStart;
    var lineEnd = documentStart.GetLineStartPosition(line + 1)
                      .GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Backward);

    // Insert the text there.
    lineEnd.InsertTextInRun(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **insert** your text at line 6 without loosing the current text

```
string[] buffer = new string[richTextBox1.Lines.Length+1];
Array.Copy(richTextBox1.Lines, 0, buffer, 0, 5);
buffer[5] = "MyText";
Array.Copy(richTextBox1.Lines, 5, buffer, 6, richTextBox1.Lines.Length - 5);
richTextBox1.Lines = buffer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally:

```
string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
lines[6] = "This Text";
richTextBox1.Lines = lines;
```

works. But you need to have this lines added before, so first you must to initiate them. For example:

```
private void RTBoxSetLines(RichTextBox rtbox, int lines)
{
    while(lines > 0)    // here you may use type you like
    {
        rtbox.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine);
        lines--;
    }
}
```

Notice that command rtbox.Clear(); will clear also all lines so after you clear all, you must declare the lines again.